# How to get list of PlotSymbol index from a Point of location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-plot

Hi i am trying to get all the `CPTPlotSymbol` index from a particular location.

Some little clear explanation about my requirement:

```
- (void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CPTPlotSymbol *selectedSymbol = [plot plotSymbolForRecordIndex:index];
    CGPoint selectedPlotLocation = [plot plotAreaPointOfVisiblePointAtIndex:index];
}
```

from the above delegate method i am getting a touched `CPTPlotSymbol` index from that index i am able to get the location of the `CPTPlotSymbol`.

But my requirement is, if more than one `CPTPlotSymbol` located in same location means i need to get all the `CPTPlotSymbol` indexes which is located in that location.

If there is any `API` available means kindly guide me to solve my problem.

I am using `CPTScatterPlot` for plotting my graph.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the index of the selected point, it should be trivial to search the plot data (via the datasource) and find any other points that fall within some distance of the selected point.

Comment: I am not getting, can you little bit clear me. There is any API is provided in Core-Plot?

Comment: No. Your datasource already knows all of the data points. Core Plot only returns the index of the closest point. If you want to find any points that are at the same (or nearby) coordinates, search the dataset and find the other points meeting your criteria.